# What does *&Var - 1.0f means?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, linear-algebra, lcg

Working with some tutorial, I met a strange C++ expression:

```
uint64_t var = ....
return (*&var) - 1.f;
```

What does this mean? Is it a reference to a pointer? What's the point of substracting `1` from reference? It should be an implementation of the LCG algorithm.

Comment: I have no idea what they are doing here.  `(*&var) - 1.f` is the same as `var - 1.f`

Comment: How do you know the tutorial was not written by a raving lunatic,  an idiot so unskilled that they think they're a genius, or someone wondering, "How many man-hours can I get people to waste with an utterly fraudulent tutorial?"

Comment: `*&var` is the equivalent of throwing your pants into mud and walking over them just so you don't get your shoes dirty

Comment: You'll need to ask the author of the tutorial what they had intended by that code.

Comment: Depending on the magnitude of `var` it will return one minus var as a float. Or possibly something else close since the vast majority of possible numbers `var` can contain are not exactly representable as floats,

Comment: Can you link the tutorial so we can see the full context?  There are obscure situations where `*&var` might actually have a useful effect, but it does seem more likely that the author is just confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var` is an identifier. It names a variable.

The unary `&` operator is the addressof operator. The result of addressof operator is a pointer to the object named by its operand. `&var` is a pointer to the variable `var`.

The unary `*` operator is the indirection operator. Given a pointer operand, it indirects through that pointer and the result is an lvalue to the pointed object. It is an inverse of the addressof operator.

When you get the address to an object, and then indirect through that pointer, the resulting value is the object whose address you had taken. Essentially, in this case `*&var` is an unnecessarily complicated way to write `var`.

> What's the point of substracting 1 from reference?

In this case, the referred value is an integer. The point of subtracting 1.f from an integer is to get a smaller value of floating point type.